# How to get parent element to grow with content using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I cannot seem to get this just right. I've been all over trying to find a solution to be able to have 3 inline-block elements that will grow to the tallest content with vertical borders. It's the borders that are making this so difficult. If I didn't need the borders, I'd be fine but I can't do without them.

What I have works, sort of...  If I resize the browser window, and the left element is the tallest, everything looks fine; the borders are all 100% and the parent div grows with the content inside.

However, if the center or the right div have the tallest content, the vertical borders fall short of 100%. I thought to fix this I would give the middle and right elements a 100% height. This does bring the borders to the ground when I resize but now, the parent no longer grows with the tallest element and the content bleeds out. please see the attached pic.

Can someone please help me get this fixed? [Live on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wucataxe/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #wrapper {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        border-top:1px solid #000;
        border-bottom:2px solid #000;
      }
      #wrapper .col {
        float:left;
        width:33%;
        display:inline-block;
      }
      #wrapper .col:nth-child(1) {
        border-right:2px solid #000;
     }
      #wrapper .col:nth-child(2) {
        border-right:2px solid #000;
        height:100%;
      }
      #wrapper .col div {
        padding:10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(window).on('load resize', function(){
        var $div = $('#wrapper .col');
        var max = 0;
        $.each($div, function(){
          if(parseInt($(this).outerHeight()) > max){
            max = parseInt($(this).outerHeight())
            $("#wrapper").css('height', max + 'px');
          }
        });
      }).resize();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="col">
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
1<br>
1<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

**EDIT:**

I'd like to add that if anyone has a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, I'm very open.

Comment: why are you using parseInt? this can be done without parseInt.

Comment: C-Link, it's a snippet I got from SO. I'm no JavaScript expert so it may not be what I need.

Comment: Won't you be able to fix this by switching your `display` to `display: table-cell;` and `display: table-row;` on the parent?

Comment: @user3008011, as it turned out, that was exactly the solution. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do this, you can do it using html and css.

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/Puu3u/

css:

```
 #wrapper {
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    display:table;
  }
  #wrapper .col {
    width:33%;
    display:table-cell;
  }
  #wrapper .col:nth-child(1) {
    border-right:2px solid #000;
 }
  #wrapper .col:nth-child(2) {
    border-right:2px solid #000;
  }
  #wrapper .col {
    padding:10px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col">
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
       1<br />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       1<br />
       1<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy cow. This works. Give me a minute to test this better in my project

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of `table-cell`. Thank you for this.

Comment: Excellent. I'd been trying to find the HTML/CSS solution, and while I'd thrown `display: table-cell` at it, I forgot to put `display: table` around it! Doh.

Comment: Ah, yes. Ideally when using `display:table`, you should follow the structure of an actual table so next would be `display:table-row` and finally `display:table-cell`. But just the `table` followed by `table-cell` works well when you only have 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, with `float: left;`, you can't use CSS to tell them to be the height of their container anymore.

I expect there's a better overall HTML/CSS solution (don't shoot me, but this looks an awful lot like a table), but with that markup, your best bet is probably sizing the elements directly: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/wucataxe/5)

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  var $div = $('#wrapper .col');
  var max = 0;

  // let them all size naturally
  $div.css('height', '');

  // now find the max
  $div.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.outerHeight();
    if (height > max) {
      max = height;
    }
  });
  // then apply it
  $div.each(function(){
    $(this).css('height', max);
  });
}).resize();
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the info on floats, I didn't know that. That will save me some hair in the future. I'll give your example a try now. Thank you.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Appreciate it. But I want to know why css() method is not working inside finding max function

Comment: TJ, thank you! This works. I could care less what it looks like. :) If it works, that's all I need. You know, there really needs to be more options for 100% height.

Comment: TJ, thank you for all your help. I had to accept the answer above. He came up with a pure CSS method of doing it. `display:table-cell` is what did it.

Comment: @NaN: I would have accepted that one too. I've been trying to come up with one, but although I'd tried `table-cell`, I'd forgotten to put a `display: table` around it! Doh!

Comment: No, don't feel bad. I'm also kicking myself for that. Wow, and so simple too!